# ORDER BY in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to perform various sorts, depending on the value of the column. If column b is 1 then the following query:

```
select * from a
```

If column b is 0 then the following query:

```
select * from a order by c desc, b
```

How to do this in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO #b1 FROM a WHERE b = 1
SELECT * INTO #b2 FROM a WHERE b = 0 ORDER BY 1 Desc

SELECT * FROM #b1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM #b2

ORDER BY b DESC

DROP TABLE #b1
DROP TABLE #b2
```

Comment: very minor quibble since the tables and columns are obviously phony, but the From clauses should be `FROM a`

Comment: that query sort all selection by c desc, b

Comment: Sorry Xaver you're right that didn't work have changed it to use temp tables which means you can order by b too.

Comment: it all OK. actually b this is datetime of our timezone with, taking into account daylight saving time, c flag of summer time. the second query should be executed in day of changing time from summer to winter. in result i want result sorted by date but when the day is the day of changing i must use  ORDER BY 1 Desc sorting. can i do that using just query without stored procedure and cursors?

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN b = 0 THEN C END DESC, 
    CASE WHEN b = 0 THEN b END
```

Comment: that query sort all selection by c desc, b

Comment: if b = 1 it sorts by null, null. i.e. it doesn't sort at all

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't supply an order criteria for the case b = 0 and T-SQL has no expression for physical order it would be necessary to use dynamic sql here. Please check first in which order you want the results for b = 0.